# Problem with creating an .exe out of my Python script via Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pycharm, exe, torch

I'm trying to create an exe out of my Python script. After a long journey of problem solving, I finally made it with Pyinstaller. I got a build folder, a dist folder, and the needed exe file.

Now, when I try to run the program, it doesn't work, although it does work in my IDE, PyCharm. If I just click on it, the cmd just opens for a ms and closes right away. If I start it via the cmd, it shows the error you can see below.

Normally there should be a main_window generated by my script, and like I said, it works when I start it from pycharm directly, so the code shouldn't be the problem.

I need the program on another PC without Pycharm at all, so I definitely need this exe file. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_>main_.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_.py", line 7, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\__init__.py", line 643, in <module>
    from .functional import *  # noqa: F403
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\functional.py", line 6, in <module>
    import torch.nn.functional as F
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\nn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .modules import *  # noqa: F403
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\nn\modules\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .linear import Identity, Linear, Bilinear, LazyLinear
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .. import functional as F
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\nn\functional.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .._jit_internal import boolean_dispatch, _overload, BroadcastingList1, BroadcastingList2, BroadcastingList3
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\_jit_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    import torch.package._mangling as package_mangling
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\package\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .package_exporter import EmptyMatchError, PackageExporter, PackagingError
  File "C:\Users\messlaptop\PycharmProjects\Source_code\dist\main_\torch\package\package_exporter.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pickletools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pickletools'
[8896] Failed to execute script 'main_' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Image of the error isn't showing. Can you copy the error text into your question

Comment: Sorry, didnt see this. done!

Comment: Can you post your command that you are executing please. Could you also indicate if you are using a virtual enviroment (venv, pyenv, virtual-env) and that you have made sure that it is activated when you are running pyinstaller

Comment: I directed into the folder and then just enterd the name of my exe to start it.
I work with a venv.
i dont know if it was activated or how i do this.

Comment: @DSculte If you're using a venv and because the errors appear to be import errors; my first guess would be because Pyinstaller isn't bundling everything you need. Copied from a previous comment of mine about using the Pyinstaller `.spec` file "As for the imports, if you are using a virtual environment then set up a variable within the `.spec` file to the `site-packages` directory `packages_dir = '/your-venv/Lib/site-packages'` and then add `packages_dir` to the pathex section of your `.spec` e.g. `pathex=['.', packages_dir]`"

Comment: @Meshi Thx, I tried it, but it didnt work.. Showing the exact same error